# Most efficient way to periodically delete all entries in database older than a month

Tags: mysql, database, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to most efficiently manage a database table and get rid of old entries that will never be accessed. Yes they could probably easily be persisted for many years but I'd just like to get rid of them. I could do this maybe once every month.  Would it be more efficient to copy the entries I want to keep into a new table then simply delete the old table. Or should a query manually delete each entry after that threshhold that I set.

I'm using MySQL with JPA/JPQL JEE6 with entity annotations and Java persistence manager.

Thanks

Comment: if the ones that i want to keep is say 2% of the entire table. Does it make more sense to copy those to a new table and then remove the old table?

Comment: What's wrong with the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362362/how-to-continuously-remove-anything-older-than-the-newst-10-entries-of-a-mysqlda?

Comment: Those aren't answers to how to remove the items. The responses suggest never deleting which isn't really an answer to the question. The one response mentioning a delete admits that it is innefficient.

Comment: It's inefficient if you run it again and again. If you run it once a month, who cares?

Comment: Wouldn't a query like that take O(n) time to compare each value? Is there a faster way?

Comment: Don't try to optimize before measuring that you have a performance problem. Try the query first, and then try to optimize if it's really too slow. Databases are very fast, and the number of rows you plan to have in the table is very small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single delete query will be the most efficient solution.

Copying data from one database to another can be lengthy if you have a lot of data to keep. It means you have to retrieve all the data with a single query (or multiple, if you want to batch), and issue a lot of insert statements in the other database.

Using JPQL, you can issue a single query to delete all old statements, something like

```
DELETE FROM Entity e WHERE e.date = ?
```

This will translated to a single SQL query, and the database will take care of deleting all the unwanted records.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to design the table with [range or list PARTITIONING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html), and then you can use ALTER TABLE to drop or truncate old partitions.

This is much quicker than using DELETE, but it may complicate other uses of the table.